# How to refer to other things in R loop

Tags: r, loops

Say that I have this data:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(num=c(1:6), val=c('1998-99', '1999-00', '2000-01', '2001-02', '2002-03', '2003-04'))
```

I then have several things that would be useful to figures out, mainly about how the values in a loop refer to other values and how to automate this process.

It would be best to put this in a loop. How to do so with data frame names? In other words, how to refer to the name of a data.frame in a loop?

```
data03 <- filter(data, num<=1)
data04 <- filter(data, num<=2)
data05 <- filter(data, num<=3)
data06 <- filter(data, num<=4)
data07 <- filter(data, num<=5)
data08 <- filter(data, num<=6)
```

Then, how to make this loop work and simplified?

```
for (i in c(03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08)) {
    #I want to print the number corresponding to i
    if(i=="03") print(1)
    if(i=="04") print(2)
    if(i=="05") print(3)
    if(i=="06") print(4)
    if(i=="07") print(5)
    if(i=="08") print(6)
    #I want to get the value corresponding to i for the plot title
    if(i=="03") title="1998-99"
    if(i=="04") title="1999-00"
    if(i=="05") title="2000-01"
    if(i=="06") title="2001-02"
    if(i=="07") title="2002-03"
    if(i=="08") title="2003-04"
    #I want to open the data frame, data+i
    df <- paste(data,i) 
    #I want to plot, using the title saved above
    plot(df$num, main=title)
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do in the end. What you're suggesting here is not really good data-manipulation, might be much more effort than required, and may not do what you need in the end. One issue right now is that `c(03,04,...)` will never match one of `"03"`, `"04", etc.

Comment: I want to make six plots, one for each data frame. Each plot should have a title corresponding to the year. Eg., the plot for data frame data03 should have title 1998-99. I want the loop index to somehow easily refer to both the data.frame and the year title.

Comment: @bill999 My update is completed. Please see my answer. There is no need to use for loop in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a for loop. You can use `lapply` the output is a list and you can further use `lapply` for subsequent analysis.

```
lapply(1:6, function(x) data %>% filter(num <= x))
# [[1]]
#   num     val
# 1   1 1998-99
# 
# [[2]]
#   num     val
# 1   1 1998-99
# 2   2 1999-00
# 
# [[3]]
#   num     val
# 1   1 1998-99
# 2   2 1999-00
# 3   3 2000-01
# 
# [[4]]
#   num     val
# 1   1 1998-99
# 2   2 1999-00
# 3   3 2000-01
# 4   4 2001-02
# 
# [[5]]
#   num     val
# 1   1 1998-99
# 2   2 1999-00
# 3   3 2000-01
# 4   4 2001-02
# 5   5 2002-03
# 
# [[6]]
#   num     val
# 1   1 1998-99
# 2   2 1999-00
# 3   3 2000-01
# 4   4 2001-02
# 5   5 2002-03
# 6   6 2003-04
```

And here is the complete code to filter the data frame and then create plots.

```
dat <- lapply(1:6, function(x) data %>% filter(num <= x))

lapply(dat, function(x){
  plot(x$num, main = x$val[nrow(x)])
})
```

Comment: Code golf (and miniscule reduction in code stack): internal code of `filter(data, num <= x)` ... or are you assuming/inferring there is more code that would otherwise use (and benefit from) `magrittr`'s pipe?

Comment: @r2evans Sorry. I am using the `filter` function from `dplyr` like OP. I am working on the second part of OP's question, which is generating plots.

Comment: I understand ... I was just suggesting the use of `dplyr::filter`, I was just thinking that the `%>%` was unnecessary in this (likely over-simplified) example. No sweat, there's likely more to it in reality.

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I agree with you that `%>%` is not necessary in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your issue you are asking how can you refer to data.frame elements without referencing their names.

In that case assuming you have data.frame `test.df` we can use `[[]]` to access them like this

```
test.df <- data.frame(first=rnorm(10),second=rnorm(10))
test.df$first
[1]  0.8447835 -0.7210152 -1.6379253 -1.5695393 -1.2467788 -1.9273583  0.5633265 -0.4186060  1.3478030 -0.4379999
test.df[[1]]
[1]  0.8447835 -0.7210152 -1.6379253 -1.5695393 -1.2467788 -1.9273583  0.5633265 -0.4186060  1.3478030 -0.4379999
test.df$first == test.df[[1]]
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

You can then do things like use this index for looping over.

Talking more specifically to your data if all you want is to print the number with the title in val you can just do this.

```
for(i in 1:length(data$num){
   plot(data$num[[i]],main=paste(data$val[[i]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a much better way to solve this problem than how you are trying to do it, but to make your idea work you just need to get the data frames in a list, and iterate over its indices.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(num=c(1:6), val=c('1998-99', '1999-00', '2000-01', '2001-02', '2002-03', '2003-04'))

data_lst <- list(
  data03 = filter(data, num<=1),
  data04 = filter(data, num<=2),
  data05 = filter(data, num<=3),
  data06 = filter(data, num<=4),
  data07 = filter(data, num<=5),
  data08 = filter(data, num<=6))

for (i in seq_along(data_lst)) {
  print(i)
  title = data[2][-1]
  print(title)
  df <- data_lst[[i]]
  plot(df$num, main=title)
}
```